Does an equivalent of the condition number for the error in system coefficients of a linear equation system exist
Let's assume that a system
$$
[A]\overline{x} = \overline{b}
$$
is given.
The normal condition number assigns an upper bound to the relative error in $\overline{x}$ based on the error in $\overline{b}$.
Is there an equivalent thing which would relate the relative error in $\overline{x}$ to the relative error in $[A]$, assuming that $\overline{b}$ is known perfectly?

Theorem 2.6.2 (Golub & Van Loan)
Suppose
$$
\begin{aligned}
Ax &= b, &A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, \ 0 \neq b\in\mathbb{R}^n,\\
(A+\Delta A)y &= b+\Delta b, &\Delta A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, \ \Delta b\in\mathbb{R}^n,
\end{aligned}
$$
with $\|\Delta A\| \leq \epsilon \|A\|$ and $\|\Delta b\| \leq \epsilon \|b\|$. If $\epsilon \kappa(A) = r < 1$, then $A+\Delta A$ is nonsingular and
$$
\frac{\|y-x\|}{\|x\|} \leq \frac{2\epsilon}{1-r} \kappa(A).
$$
In your case, $\Delta b = 0$, so we can take $\epsilon = \frac{\|\Delta A\|}{\|A\|}$ and we then have
$$
\frac{\|y-x\|}{\|x\|} \leq \frac{2\kappa(A)}{1-\kappa(A)\frac{\|\Delta A\|}{\|A\|}} \frac{\|\Delta A\|}{\|A\|}.
$$
Golub, Gene; Van Loan, Charles F., Matrix computations., Baltimore, MD: The Johns Hopkins Univ. Press. xxvii, 694 p. (1996). ZBL0865.65009.
